# How to resolve findfont error after auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I'm using matplotlib to convert some files to pdf.

```
fig.savefig(pdf_folder_path+"\\" + filename)
```

When I run the python code (inside visual code) no errors are shown on the console.
But when I use auto-py-to-exe (or pyinstaller) a bunch of errors like these are printed:

```
findfont: Font family 'txt_____' not found.
```

I alreay tried to clear my fontcache but nothing happens.